# .Net XML serialized array has elements with xmlns in them and fails subsequent XSLT Transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-serialization, transform, xml-namespaces

I have a Aspx.Net web page that is creating a report from an array coming in via WCF. The array is converted to XML and then run through a translation to get the html report.

The array is of a class containing simple strings and numbers.

I am using the serialize process on the array to create the XML:

```
XmlDocument xmlData = new XmlDocument();

// serialize the array so we can transform
XmlSerializer slz = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ReportData[]));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    slz.Serialize(stream, responseMain);
    stream.Position = 0;
    xmlData.Load(stream);
}
```

When the XML is generated, each element inside an array element contains a xmlns="namespace of the object" attribute:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ArrayOfReportData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetPaymentOptionReportData>
            <Name xmlns="http://mynamespace.ServiceContracts">SMITH, JAMES E               </Name>
            <IdNumber xmlns="http://mynamespace.ServiceContracts">01081-01        </IdNumber>
            <AcctDate xmlns="http://mynamespace.ServiceContracts">2011-09-19T00:00:00</AcctDate>
            <NumberOfVisits xmlns="http://mynamespace.ServiceContracts">12</NumberOfVisits>
            <Fee xmlns="http://mynamespace.ServiceContracts">329.00</Fee>
        </GetPaymentOptionReportData>
      </ArrayOfReportData>
```

This causes the transform to fail. I attempted a few things with setting the namespace (probably not the correct way). The only way I found to fix the problem  was to run a Regex on the innerXml of the data after I serialize it and prior to the transform to remove all occurrences of the offending xmlns attribute (thanks to Ultrapico's expresso for making this easy to do these days!):

```
/// <summary>
///  Regular expression built for C# on: Thu, Dec 29, 2011, 08:14:26 AM
///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.3634, http://www.ultrapico.com
///  
///  A description of the regular expression:
///  
///  \s?xmlns\s?=\s?"
///      Whitespace, zero or one repetitions
///      xmlns
///      Whitespace, zero or one repetitions
///      =
///      Whitespace, zero or one repetitions
///      "
///  [Protocol]: A named capture group. [\w+]
///      Alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
///  :\/\/
///      :
///      Literal /
///      Literal /
///  [Domain]: A named capture group. [[\w@][\w.:@]+]
///      [\w@][\w.:@]+
///          Any character in this class: [\w@]
///          Any character in this class: [\w.:@], one or more repetitions
///  Literal /, zero or one repetitions
///  Any character in this class: [\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,], any number of repetitions
///  "
///  This regex captures the occurences of 
///
/// </summary>
Regex xmlnsRegex = new Regex(
        "\\s?xmlns\\s?=\\s?\"(?<Protocol>\\w+):\\/\\/(?<Domain>[\\w@]" +
        "[\\w.:@]+)\\/?[\\w\\.?=%&=\\-@/$,]*\"",
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
     | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
     | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
     | RegexOptions.Compiled
     );

// take out namespace attributes inside object elements 
xmlData.InnerXml = xmlnsRegex.Replace(xmlData.InnerXml, "");
```

This seems like a kludge, so I was hoping some XML guru could give me some assistance.

Comment: Please post the definition of the `ReportData` class. Also, I presume there are derived types? If so, then please post the `GetPaymentOptionReportData` type.

Comment: Since class is auto-generated, I'm hoping not to modify it on the consumer side of the WCF service. That is the difficulty - how to Serialize with the needed additions without having to change the source web service or add attributes to auto-generated class. Either could solve the problem, but one involves opening a class that is not part of my solution, and the other requires that if the interface is updated, I have to re-apply changes. With that effort, I could have just created the xml manually/iteratively.

I can post code, but have to extract it to an example. Probably not today. 
thanks!

Comment: I didn't say anything about modifying the classes on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to register each of those namespaces within the stylesheet. You do this on the `stylesheet` element, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns1="http://mynamespace.ServiceContracts" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

And then rewrite the XPath expressions and match patterns in the stylesheet so that they use these prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This looks like the way I should go, however, I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Since the element includes the namespace, and the element name does not have that prefix, I am guessing that somehow in the serialization I would have to get those elements prefixed with the "ns1:" ie:

    <ns1:Name xmlns="http://mynamespace.ServiceContracts">...

specified in the stylesheet. I see that I can add a namespace, but the docs I have read so far seem to say that each element gets its own namespace and does not inherit it from the parent.

Comment: @RobbSadler - 1) It does not matter what prefix you choose. The prefix is arbitrary. All you're doing in the XSLT is saying "I want to refer to elements in this namespace using this prefix." You can then use that prefix in your XPath to select elements. It doesn't have to match anything in the source XML. 2) Namespaces *are* inherited from ancestors.